# What is a pure-jump process?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have been reading some notes and they keep referring (without definition) to a "pure jump process".

On wiki I can only find a reference in the Levy-Ito decomposition theorem, but still I can't find the definition

Can you guys help?

Comment: What is the context/the topic of these notes? For example, if $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Lévy process, I would call $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ a pure jump process if there is no drift- and diffusion part. However, in my experience, "pure jump process" can mean almost everything (...or nothing...) depending on the author of the book/paper/...

Comment: @saz but how do you define which part is drift and which part is diffusion without the levy ito decomposition? For example on wikipedia, in the statement of the levy ito decomposition, it is mentioned the pure jump process. What does that mean in that context?

Comment: Lévy processes can be characterized by the Lévy triplet. If $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Lévy process with triplet $(b,Q,\nu)$, then $b$ is called drift part and $Q$ diffusion part. So, a pure-jump (Lévy) process has triplet $(0,0,\nu)$; some authors allow drifts, i.e. call a Lévy process a pure jump process if the triplet is of the form $(b,0,\nu)$.

Comment: @saz uhm okay, seems fair enough :) I'll keep it mind, thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As saz mentioned in the comments, the definition of pure jump processes differs between authors & papers. The way it was defined in my class (using Cinlar's Probability and Stochastics textbook) was

> A process in $\mathbb{R}^d$, where $X_t$ is equal to the sum of the sizes of its jumps during the interval $[0,t]$, i.e. for almost every $\omega$, $$X_t(\omega) = \sum_{s \in D_\omega \cap [0,t]} \Delta X_s(\omega), t \in \mathbb{R}_+,$$
>   where $D_\omega = \{t > 0: \Delta X_t(\omega) \neq 0\}$ (the discontinuity set for the path $X(\omega)$) and $\Delta X_t(\omega)$ is the jump size at time $t$, i.e. $$\Delta X_t (\omega) = X_{t+}(\omega) - X_{t-}(\omega),$$ i.e. the process jumps from its left-limit to its right limit.

One example of a pure jump processes is the drift-less increasing Levy process.

Comment: +1 nice.. But are we implicitly assuming that there are only a countable number of jumps in every interval $[0,t]$? (That is, $D_{\omega}$ is at most countable?)

Comment: @Ant If X is Poisson, the set $D_\omega$ can be an infinite countable set for almost every $\omega$, but $D_\omega \cap (s,u)$ is finite for all $0 \leq s < u <infty$.

If X is a stable process, $D_\omega \cap (s,u)$ is infinite. However, for every $\varepsilon >0$, there can be at most finitely many $t$ in $D_\omega$ \cap $(s,u)$ for which the magnitude $|\Delta X_t(\omega)|$ exceeds $\varepsilon$, since otherwise we would have a contradiction by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.

I suggest you read it in the book I mentioned, you can find it on pages 316-317.

Comment: oh very nice. Thanks for the reference ;-)

Comment: Holy blast from the past, batman! Good point.